# How to change style (Color ; Icon ; Indicator ; Size etc..) Indicator of Tabs with Material-UI ⚛️ React Web?

Tags: reactjs, tabs, material-ui, material-design, appbar

I implementing **TabsBar** in my **Appbar** for my React Desktop Application.
But I really have a hard time stylizing the Tabs part. If anyone can help me with clear explanations, that would be great.  I want to add Icons to the right of the text. Change the color of the tab indicator and put it on top as on the picture example. I'm a beginner. I searched for 4 days but the I ask because I block

We have two colors :(#738889) & (#006F85) for actived Tab.

[AppBar with Tabs Designed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rt3V0.png)

Voici Mon code actuel ci-dessous :

```js
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import SearchIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Search';
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import { fade, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { ReactComponent as BrandLogo } from '../Assets//PriceWanted/BrandLogo.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Icon_MicroPhone } from '../Icons/Icon_MicroPhone.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Icon_Separation } from '../Icons/Icon_Separation.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Icon_Global } from '../Icons/Icon_Global.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Icon_Lightning } from '../Icons/Icon_Lightning.svg';
import { ReactComponent as Icon_Shipment_Boat } from '../Icons/Icon_Shipment_Boat.svg';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
   Tabs: {
   marginLeft: 50,
  },
  search: {
    position: 'relative',
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('backgroundColor'),
    marginRight: 10,
    
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.black, 0.15),
    '&:hover': {
    backgroundColor: fade(theme.palette.common.black, 0.70),
    boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(25, 1, 12, .2)',
    },
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
      marginLeft: theme.spacing(3),
      width: 'auto',
    },
  },
  inputRoot: {
    color: '#2F6164',
    '&:hover': {
     color: '#b2ebf2',
    },
  },
  inputInput: {
    padding: theme.spacing(1),
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(2.5)}px)`,
    paddingRight: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(2.5)}px)`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create('width'),
    width: '90%',
    flex: 1,
    [theme.breakpoints.up('sm')]: {
    borderColor: 'grey',
    '&:focus': {
    borderColor: 'green',
      },
    width: '35ch',
    '&:focus': {
    width: '50ch',
      },
    },
  }, 
  searchIcon: {
    padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
    color: '#889FA0',
    height: '100%',
    position: 'absolute',
    display: 'flex',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  iconButton: {
    padding:5,
    marginRight: 6,
    marginLeft: 6,
  },
  Toolbar: {
  alignItems:'center'
  },
}));

TabPanel.propTypes = {children: PropTypes.node,index: PropTypes.any.isRequired,value: PropTypes.any.isRequired,};

function TabPanel(props) {const { children, value, index, ...other } = props;}
function a11yProps(index) {return{id: `simple-tab-${index}`,'aria-controls': `simple-tabpanel-${index}`,};}
  
export default function SimpleTabs() {
const classes = useStyles();
const StyledButton = withStyles({
              root : {background: 'linear-gradient(270deg,#00DBFF 0%, #021118 61.57%, #000000 100%)',
          '&:hover': {background:'linear-gradient(90deg, #00DBFF 0%, #000000 100%)',},
           position: 'relative',
       borderRadius: 4,
             border: 1,
              color: 'White',
             height: 35,
            padding: '10 5px',
          boxShadow: '0 3px 5px 2px rgba(0px 4px 4px #CBCBCB)',
         marginLeft: 1,
     justifyContent:'center'},
      textTransform: 'capitalize',})(Button);
const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);
const handleChange = (event,newValue) => {setValue(newValue);};

return (
                <div className={classes.grow}>

                <AppBar position="static">
                <AppBar style={{background: '#FFFFFF'}}>
        
                <Toolbar>
                
                <BrandLogo/>
                 
                <div className={classes.search}>

                      <div className={classes.searchIcon}>
                      <SearchIcon />
                      </div>
                      <InputBase placeholder="Marque,Modèle..."classes={{ root: classes.inputRoot,input: classes.inputInput,}}
                                 inputProps={{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}/>
                      <IconButton className={classes.iconButton} aria-label="menu">
                      <Icon_MicroPhone/>
                      </IconButton>
                      </div>   
                
                   <Icon_Separation style={{ flex: 1 }}/>

                <Tabs 
                                    value={value}
                                 onChange={handleChange}
                                  variant="fullWidth"
                           indicatorColor="secondary"
                                textColor="secondary"
                               aria-label="icon label tabs example">   

                               <Tab label="LIVE DEALS" {...a11yProps(0)}   icon={<Icon_Lightning />}/>
                               <Tab label="GLOBAL STOCK" {...a11yProps(1)} icon={<Icon_Global/>}/>
                               <Tab label="TRANSPORT" {...a11yProps(2)}    icon={<Icon_Shipment_Boat/>}/>
                </Tabs>
                     
                <StyledButton 
                                  variant="contained"
                                    color="primary"
                                className={classes.StyledButton}
                                  endIcon={<Icon>power_settings_new&style</Icon>}>
                                  CONNEXION
                </StyledButton>
            
                </Toolbar>

                </AppBar>
                </AppBar>
    
               </div>);}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: are you able to recreate this issue in http://codesandbox.io?

Comment: Open It in full screen mode.https://codesandbox.io/s/practical-diffie-8c7e7?file=/src/App.js